# I use mpdf to gen pdf but css is not working (border-collapse)

Tags: html, css, mpdf

I use mpdf in my code. I copy the css code form google, but I don't have knowledge about it.
I want to create table `border-collapse: collapse;` in css but it is not working.
Currently the border is double, but I want the border to be single.

Please tell me how to set css `border-collapse: collapse;` in mpdf

```
<?
require_once('connect.php');
require_once('mpdf/mpdf.php');
ob_start();
?>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<style type="text/css">
<!--
@page rotated { size: landscape; }
.style1 {
    font-family: "TH SarabunPSK";
    font-size: 18pt;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.style2 {
    font-family: "TH SarabunPSK";
    font-size: 16pt;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.style3 {
    font-family: "TH SarabunPSK";
    font-size: 16pt;

}
.style5 {cursor: hand; font-weight: normal; color: #000000;}
.style9 {font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 12px; }
.style11 {font-size: 12px}
.style13 {font-size: 9}
.style16 {font-size: 9; font-weight: bold; }
.style17 {font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; }

table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
table tr td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

-->
</style>
    <html>
    <head>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
<table width="700" border='1'  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <th  width="10" align="center">no</th>
        <th  width="400" align="center">list</th>
        <th  width="50" align="center">unit</th>
        <th  width="50" align="center">num</th>
        <th  width="80" align="center">price</th>
        <th colspan='2' width="100" align="center">total</th>
        <th  width="100" align="center">note</th>
      </tr>
<tr>
<td>test1</td>
<td>test2</td>
<td>test3</td>
<td>test4</td>
<td>test5</td>
<td>test6</td>
<td>test7</td>
<td>test8</td>
</tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Your 3rd TH isnt closed properly